# How can I move between computers while maintaining the user's session?

Tags: user-profiles, windows-server-2012-r2, fast-user-switching

I run a small home domain network so that everything is managed centrally- programs, files, etc. There are a few users and both laptops & desktops are used on the domain.

For many reasons I often find myself switching between my laptop & desktop, and this means I have to log-off & log-on again on the other computer, meaning that the current user session is lost.

I know that it's possible to switch the user session from one computer to another, in the following fashion:

1. Computer 1 is logged on
2. User logs onto computer 2, user session from computer 1 is transferred to computer 2
3. Computer 1 is logged off

What is this feature called, and how do I go about implementing this?

I did try searching for such a feature, but I couldn't find anything relevant. I consider myself experienced when it comes to computers but domain/network admin is where I don't have much experience, so please bear with me if this is something simple.

This is with Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter, & all client machines run Windows 8.1 Pro.

The server itself is a small-form-factor (SFF) desktop that I picked up for free a week or so ago, I have plans to upgrade it but it might be better to simply replace it with a better machine. At the moment its specifications are enough for its use:

- CPU: Intel Core 2 Duo E7500
- RAM: 8GB DDR2 800MHz
- HDD: 320GB (*planned upgrade to 4x 2TB drives, but this might be scrapped if I'm just going to build a new server machine*)

Comment: You say *"I know that it's possible to switch the user session from one computer to another"*.  How do you know this?

Comment: @misha256 We had this at my college a few years back; they were Windws 7 machines & you could easily switch from one machine to another without losing what you were doing. I don't know much about the internals of how it worked because that project was scrapped after three months; problem with resources perhaps?

Comment: Updated question with hardware specifications.

Comment: You're probably thinking of [Terminal Services](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755399(v=ws.10).aspx).

Comment: @BenN You gave me a starting point there. Looks like what I want is [Virtual Desktops](http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2013/04/25/step-by-step-deploying-virtual-desktops-with-windows-server-2012.aspx), and there's no way the current server machine would be able to run virtual desktops for multiple users. Time to build a new server machine I suppose. Might be a good idea to add that as an answer (with reference to Virtual Desktops since that seems to be what I need).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Adding as an answer at the request of OP.)

The situation you describe is provided by **session virtualization**, and you will need a more powerful server, specifically one with a [SLAT-enabled processor](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/uk_faculty_connection/archive/2012/10/24/hyper-v-list-of-slat-capable-cpus-for-hosts.aspx) and a GPU, if you're serious about this.

The [Terminal Services](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755399(v=ws.10).aspx) server role from Windows Server 2003 moves almost all of the computing into a central server, making individual machines something like the dumb terminals of old. It is now called [Remote Desktop Services](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee236407.aspx), and provides the Virtual Desktop Infrastructure.

Install the Remote Desktop Services role (you might need extra CALs) and follow Microsoft's [deployment guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/dd647502(WS.10).aspx), which will be a rather large undertaking.

Comment: Just a side question: it it possible to assign a physical GPU to a specific VD?

Comment: @bob Install the RemoteFX adapter inside the VM ("Enabling and Disabling Hardware Acceleration" on [this page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2014/06/06/understanding-and-evaluating-remotefx-vgpu-on-windows-server-2012-r2.aspx)). See [this other page](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/16652.remotefx-vgpu-setup-and-configuration-guide-for-windows-server-2012.aspx) for more requirements. [Another page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2014/11/05/remotefx-vgpu-updates-in-windows-server-next.aspx) suggests that there will be improvements in Windows Server 2016.